# Collect results of many sql server jobs

Tags: sql-server

I intend to create a simple job on a bunch (100+) sql servers (of differing flavors) that does a simple automated query periodically (like weekly). These jobs then need to push the result out to a central location. What is going to be a reliable, minimal config way to push those results?

I was thinking of converting the result set to text/xml and posting to a url. It seems that doing anything http from tsql is not simple, or standard. I think a CLR stored proc is probably my best option. I've been shying away from it because of the multi-step deployment.

(I also considered using a script that connects to every server and executes the query. I rejected this because of security concerns in introducing a shared account across all our servers.)

Can anyone suggest better options?

Thanks

Comment: Linked Server where you push the data to a single table on a single server. If you don't like the Linked Server, you could use a ROWSET. I do this often. Easy, fast and ... easy.

Answer (score 1):

I've created an SSIS package that connects to multiple servers and runs a query and copies that data to a central SQL server that I report against.   Just took a while to get the query to contain all the information I needed but the SSIS package is pretty straight forward, so may be an easier option than txt/xml

Comment: One thing I would be interested in is how you go about connecting to each server within the SSIS package [e.g. connect to table with list of servers and dynamically change OLE DB manager through expression variables]?

Comment: Shawn, depends.  The need I had at first was for 3 servers at a particular location so the SSIS had oledb connections to each machine.  For a larger project I had a database with servers names in it that wanted to monitor so I looped through and modified the source's oledb connection through expressions.

Comment: Hey @JeffArlt thanks for the answer, but what you have described is a task that reaches "into" the sql servers. I want each server to push the data "out". Hope that makes sense.

Comment: gotcha, not a big fan of linked servers but could you use one so that it queries and pushes the data to another server?  Thinking you could have a scheduled job that runs the query and pushes to one common server.  Think there's going to be many ways to do this just depends what you are most comfortable with and how complex you want it to be.  I just prefer to pull data so can have one process to pull the data vs. maintain individual processes on multiple servers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend having a look at this blog:-

http://sqldbawithabeard.com/2014/03/31/how-i-check-hundreds-of-sql-agent-jobs-in-60-seconds-with-powershell/

There's step by step guides on how to use powershell to check jobs on multiple SQL Server instances.

Hope it helps.

Andrew

EDIT - Adding in part of powershell script

The most essential part of the powershell script that I linked to is:-

```
  # Load SMO extension
  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") | Out-   Null;

  # Get List of sql servers to check
  $sqlservers = Get-Content 'D:\sqlservers.txt';

  # Loop through each sql server from sqlservers.txt
  foreach($sqlserver in $sqlservers)
  {
     # Create an SMO Server object
     $srv = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" $sqlserver;

     # For each jobs on the server
     foreach($job in $srv.JobServer.Jobs)
     {

        $jobName = $job.Name;
        $jobEnabled = $job.IsEnabled;
        $jobLastRunOutcome = $job.LastRunOutcome;
        $Time = $job.LastRunDate;

    Write-Host $jobName $jobLastRunOutcome

     }   
  }
```

The script uses a list of servers stored in a .txt file (D:\sqlservers.txt) and then uses the SQL Server SMO extension to check all the jobs in the instances listed in the text file, saves the output to variables and then prints the variables in the console. This can then be adapted to drop the values into an excel file (as in the post).

Comment: Please ensure you provide context for your links, such as a code sample or explanation of how the process would work. In it's current state, your answer is likely to get deleted, as if the external link goes down, it becomes useles. You can read the help guide on how to write a good answere here http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Apologies, will edit the post now

Comment: I am the author of that blog and would just like to add that the script is run externally and gathers data from the SQL Server. If you wish to push the data out you can run an agent job on each server to create the excel file (you could also export to CSV) on a Share or you could use Invoke-SQLCmd to take those results and place them into a database

Answer (score 0):

Since you are managing 100+ servers you need or you will need much more information. Another solution, may be an overshot in your case, is to create an Admin database and deploy it on each instance. This DB will contain tables, SPs and agent schedules that will gather all data you need. Then all data will be sent via Replication to you main admin database.

Answer (score 0):

Job steps' output can be directed to an output file (Step -> Properties -> Advanced: Output file).  This field accepts [tokens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) so it is relatively easy to deploy a common script to every instance yet generate unique file names from each.  Direct the output to a common fileshare to which all SQL accounts have write access.  Then use a second process to read the file, process the content and clean up.  I have several monitoring tasks using this method.

---

Alternatively, on the job step's general page, click the "Type" drop-down and choose "Powershell".  Then you can use http calls or whatever else the SQL service account has rights to perform; the world is your lobster.